# Change the scale of sigmoid function to get a value between -0.5 to +.0.5?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

Right now the sigmoid function usually gives a value between 0 to 1. I want to scale it down by 0.5 to it gives value between -0.5 to 0.5 ?

How can I do it?

Comment: Subtract $\frac 12$?

Comment: You have requested that this post be deleted. But I see no reason to do this. Stack Exchange is a collective work to which you have granted an irrevocable license to display, use, and modify your work (i.e., the post). However it is possible to disassociate yourself from this post --- though not through a normal flag (which goes to volunteer site mods). You instead should use the `contact us` link at the bottom of the page to talk to SE staff. [Read here for more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96746/205676)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said it yourself: you want to **scale it down by 0.5**. So take your
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}
$$
and move it down by $0.5$:
$$
g(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}} - \frac{1}{2}
$$